# Implementing Social Login and In-app login

Tags: android, database, facebook, security, authentication

I am creating an app where we have three type of login:

1. Facebook
2. Google+
3. In-App Registration and Login.

For authentication at app level, we have kept a username and password combination.

When a user register through Facebook say, he is registered and logged in. But there is no password set for that login. If the user would again come and login, it would not allow to login. 
How do I define logic for my database so that we are able to securely implement the login and registration.
 I heard of option of identifying what type of login it is and not doing any authentication at server level for say Facebook login. But is that not compromising with security.

How do we do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a user logs in using Facebook, he'll be always able to come back to your App and log in again using Facebook.

When you use Facebook login, what you're really doing is calling Facebook API with user credentials. The first time, the user will be prompt with the dialog to authorize your App but the second time, the dialog won't show and the user will be automatically redirected to your App

See the docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3

In both cases, you'll get a confirmation in your callback call (onSuccess), at this point you can safely assume that your user has been logged in.

If you implement this code, you wouldn't need to track anything else and users would be always able to log in your App, but this is not your case.

As you want to provide your own login system + other third party login systems, what you have to do is create a user row in your database and store the user_id you get back when a user uses a third party login system. Then you check on your callback method the user_id and if it's in your database, you load the data. You can always offer the possibility to add a new password for your own login system.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old already but it is worth mentioning that not all social login providers will give you the same info and will use the exact same way of connecting.

However I found a promising solution Trusstee that is explained https://medium.com/me/stats/post/ef5d5a5a3943.

This approach has the benefit of treating all social login providers in the same way